# Insert a set of id's to database in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have some id's from the ajax code posted into a php file.it is in the format of an array.

```
$members=$_REQUEST['members'];
$temp=explode(',',$members);
$count=0;
foreach($temp as $value) {
    $count++;
}
echo $count;
print_r($temp);
```

upto this the code works.I want to insert the ids to the member_id field of my database table.I tried implode function,then it shows

> 'undefined' as error.

Comment: try to print the `$_REQUEST` result . What you are getting ?

Comment: what you want actually..You want the update qry ?

Comment: Why not just do `$count = count($temp);` instead of your loop?

Comment: So this code works? Where's the code that _doesn't_ work? And share the exact error message.

Comment: Now i have changed the code like this:$members=$_REQUEST['members'];
$temp=explode(',',$members);
$cnt=count($temp);
for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++){
$sql = "insert into projects(project_date,project_name,project_description,estimated_time_of_completion,project_members)values('$project_date','$project_name','$project_description','$esti','$temp[$i]')";
}
$exe = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if ($exe) { 
echo "success"; 
}
else {
echo "Failed";       
}

Comment: I am getting a success message.and the data has been inserted into the database table,but instead inserting  all ids in the variable to the field member_id,only the last one is inserted.how can i insert all values to the field?values are somthing like this:7,1,4.